# Android GCM can't get content of the message from the server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have written the code from the server side by JSP and it could send the message to my app.
And there is a notification on my app.

However, the content is missing.
Below is the server side code:

```
String message = "This is a test message.";
String registrationId="xxxxxx";

Sender sender = new Sender("My API key");
Message gcmMessage = new Message.Builder().addData(registrationId,message).build();
Result result=sender.send(gcmMessage, registrationId, 5);
out.println(result.toString());
```

And below is my app code part where the message received:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
    String message;
    // Message from PHP server
    message = data.getStringExtra("message");
    // Open a new activity called GCMMessageView
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMMessageView.class);
    // Pass data to the new activity
    //test
    Log.v("sky", "MESSAGE RECEIVED : "+data.getExtras().toString());
    Log.v("sky","Message:"+message);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    // Starts the activity on notification click
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Create the notification with a notification builder
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("Android GCM Tutorial")
            .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .getNotification();
    // Remove the notification on click
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

    {
        // Wake Android Device when notification received
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                        | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
        mWakelock.acquire();

        // Timer before putting Android Device to sleep mode.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                mWakelock.release();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 5000);
    }

}
```

In my `data.getExtras().toString());` part, i have got the text in my log, and seems I can't extract the message from the result:

```
04-01 19:16:45.951: V/sky(21451): MESSAGE RECEIVED : Bundle[{xx My Register ID xxx=This is a test message., collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=584034591331}]
```

May I know how to get the message?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is your error :

```
Message gcmMessage = new Message.Builder().addData(registrationId,message).build();
```

Is should be :

```
Message gcmMessage = new Message.Builder().addData("message",message).build();
```

You sent the content of your message in a parameter whose name was your registration ID, which doesn't make sense.